# IE9 shows a second scroll bar inside the window frame

Tags: javascript, browser

In my web application ,IE9 shows a second scroll bar inside the window frame, that is never used.

Second scroll bar is coming only for the browser type IE9 with compatibility view.

How should i fix this.?

[image: Without second scroll]

[image: With second scroll]

Comment: can you show me the code?

Comment: iframe? - try `scrolling="no"`

Comment: code or hosted public so that i can have a look and fix it immediately..

Comment: body
{
    background: #A8A8A8;
    font-size: .80em;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #696969;
    height: auto;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 0.814em;
    text-align: center;
    overflow-y: scroll;   

}

Comment: overflow:hidden; or something like that should (could) do the trick

Comment: Thanks, overflow:hidden removes the scroll.But the page height is changing when switch between the browser types